# Updating multiple images in database

Tags: javascript, php

Thanks in Advance

I have a problem with updating multiple images in the database. so i need a help...
what i am doing is:
In the case of update i am retrieving images data in the function and calling that function in the design page. The function includes the code of fetching images fom the data, am able to display images in the update page but am not able to update the images if any one of images is removed and then updating data so previous images is updating in the database, mean to say the previous images is coming in a form of array in the $_POST["AircraftImage"]
here is the code below:-

```
public function getimageswithaircraftid ($AircarftID){
    try{
        // Query to retrieve Aircraft Images from database...
        $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `aircraft_image` WHERE      `Aircraft_ID` = '".$AircarftID."' ");
    if (mysql_num_rows ($query) > 0){
        $tabledata = '';
        //$_POST["AircraftImage"] = array();
        $tabledata = "<th>File Name</th><th></th><th>File Size</th><th>Image Preview</th><th>Delete</th>";
        while ($execute = mysql_fetch_object ($query)){
            $filepath = $execute->uploadpath;
            $split    = explode('/', $filepath);

            $tabledata .= "<tr class=record><td>".$split[5]."</td>";
            $tabledata .= "<td><input type=text name=AircraftImage[] value=".$split[5]."::".$execute->filesize. "></td>";
            $tabledata .= "<td>".$execute->filesize."</td>";
            $tabledata .= "<td><a target=_blank href=".$execute->uploadpath."><img src=".$execute->uploadpath." height=70 width=70 /></a></td>";
            $tabledata .= "<td><a href=# id=".$execute->AircraftImageId." class=delbutton>
            <img title=Delete src=images/delete.png ></a></td></tr>";
            //$tabledata .= "<input type=text name=AircraftImage[] value=".$split[5]."::".$execute->filesize. ">";
        }
        print $tabledata;   
    }
    }
    catch(Exception $ex){

    }   
}
```

here is the code for inserting/updating images..

```
public function uploadimage ($AircraftImage = array()){
    if (!$this->Aircraft_ID){
        if (count ($AircraftImage) > 0){
        //set_time_limit (240);
        $q = mysql_query ("SELECT MAX(Aircraft_ID) as id FROM `aircraft` WHERE `IsDeleted` = 0 AND
         `User_ID` = '".$this->User_ID."'");
        $res = mysql_fetch_object ($q);
        $maxid = $res->id;
        foreach ($AircraftImage as $k=>$v){ 
            $split    = explode('::', $v);  
            $fullpath = "http://localhost/pz_serveroriginal/uploads/".$split[0];            
            //$fullpath = "http://pilotzeus.com/pz/uploads/".$split[0]; 
            $filesize = $split[1];  
        // Insert into aircraft image with full path...
        // select maxid from aircraft

        $insert_query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `aircraft_image` (`Aircraft_ID`,`uploadpath`,`filesize`)
        VALUES ('".$maxid."','".$fullpath."','".$filesize."')");
        if ($insert_query == FALSE){
            throw new Exception ("Some Error Occurred while Saving Images");
        }           

    }
    }

    }

    else{   
        if (count ($AircraftImage) > 0){
            //DELETE ALL
            $deletequery = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM `aircraft_image` WHERE `Aircraft_ID` = '".$this->Aircraft_ID."' ");
            //set_time_limit (240);
            foreach ($AircraftImage as $k=>$v){
            $split    = explode('::', $v);                          
            $fullpath = "http://localhost/pz_serveroriginal/uploads/".$split[0];            
            //$fullpath = "http://pilotzeus.com/pz/uploads/".$split[0];     
            $filesize = $split[1];  

            //check if current image is not equal to database image then insert into database
            // if image already exists or not

            $insert_query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `aircraft_image` (`Aircraft_ID`,`uploadpath`,`filesize`)
            VALUES('".$this->Aircraft_ID."','".$fullpath."','".$filesize."')");
            if ($insert_query == FALSE){
                throw new Exception ("Some Error Occurred while updating images");
            }                               
    }
}
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code you have done so far for updating images?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to update image(s) into aircraft_image table when you updating data,

```
1) You update all previous images by ID (Primary key)
           OR
2) You deleted all previous images for that particular Aircraft_ID and insert all new images for that.
```

**UPDATE :**

> For that you need to remove that particular row with jquery
>   ($('rowid').remove()), so when you delete any records from the table
>   its remove that row from the HTML also. now when you refresh that page
>   it will obviously not displaying that row even.

Let me know if you have any Query / Issues

Thanks!

Comment: the way u have said have done but the problem is suppose i have 4 rows of images data:
in first column it includes Filename
in second column it includes <input type=hidden name=AircraftImage[]>
in third column filesize
in fourth column image preview
in fifth column delete image button
so when i am deleting any image with the delete button then it is removing with the javascript from the database, but unfortunately the page is not refresh so thats why it is taking previous images array in a post....i hope u understand what i mean to say...

Comment: yes u are absolutely right but if i do so then the page is totally refreshed and it go to the top and the table is below....
i have tried with this after success location.href = url but after this done the page starts from the top and the table is below

Comment: For that you can use either AJAX or jQuery scrollTop() method for scrolling your page to particular Div Id.